# Refreshing ViewController after dismissing another ViewController in swift5 using viewDidAppear()

Tags: ios, xcode11, swift5

i am trying to dismiss my loginVC when usersignin i simply let user signings

```
if success {
dismiss(animated:true, completion:nil)
}
```

after dismissing it shows my homepage which is AuthVC another viewController.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
                    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
                   
                    if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
                        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
            

class LoginVC: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var emailField: InsetTxtField!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var pwdField: InsetTxtField!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        emailField.delegate = self
        pwdField.delegate = self
        
    }
    @IBAction func signInBtnWasPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if emailField.text != nil && pwdField.text != nil {
            AuthService.instance.loginUser(email: emailField.text!, andPassword: pwdField.text!) { (success, loginError) in
                if success {
                    print("login sucessfully")
                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    
                } else {
                    print(loginError!.localizedDescription)
                    
                }
                AuthService.instance.registerUser(email: self.emailField.text!, andPassword: self.pwdField.text!) { (success, registrationError) in
                    if success {
                        AuthService.instance.loginUser(email: self.emailField.text!, andPassword: self.pwdField.text!) { (success, nil) in
                             print("Successfully registered user")
                            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                        
                    }
                    }
                    else {
                        print(String(describing: registrationError?.localizedDescription))
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
     @IBAction func closeBtnWasPRessed(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

hope now it will be clear now.
My viewDidAppear function not get called.

Comment: I partially understand your question, can you add some additional info

Comment: which is AuthVC in this i use ..?

Comment: now i updated the question hope my issue is clear now

Comment: so you want to push from login VC  to authVC once its success or else if I am wrong.

Comment: yeah i want AuthVC to dismiss when login get success and CurrentUser not nill. it's just my viewdidAppear () not working after dismissal of LoginVC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modal view controller has UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen as modal presentation style

the parent view never disappears, so it will not call viewDidAppear.

To handle that, post a message on the NSNotificationCenter when dismissing the modal view and handle it on your parent view controller.

or

you can change `modalPresentationStyle` LoginVC to `.fullScreen`

`viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen`

example :

```
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: LoginVC())
nav.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil) // if you add navigationController

or 

let vc = LoginVC()
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: i changed modalPresentationStyle of AuthVC but its still not working.

Comment: Sorry my bad,  it should be LoginVC

Comment: hmm, where you put this code `viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen` ?

Comment: inside viewDidload(){

Comment: you're well come @NehaDixit